# Hibernate One to One mapping. Insert only foreign key rather than whole new row

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have RECEIPE table and CUISINE_ID is a foreign key of CUISINE.ID table. Is is possible while inserting new RECIPE, only CUISINE_ID is inserted and no new row in the CUISINE table.

Table structure

```
create table CUISINE(cuisine_id number primary key, name varchar2(20));

create table RECIPE(id number primary key,
                    name varchar2(25) not null,
                    cuisine_id number,
                    constraint cuisine_fk foreign key (cuisine_id) references
                    cuisine(cuisine_id));
```

Class mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cuisine")
public class Cuisine {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "cuisine_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotBlank(message = "You can not leave this empty.")
    @NotNull(message = "You can not leave this empty.")
    private String name;


@Entity
@Table(name = "recipe")
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cuisine_id")
    private Cuisine cuisine;
```

Once I get RECEIPE class being populated from JSP page, I get following from the modelAttribute

```
Recipe [id=0, name=Burger, cuisine=Cuisine [id=0, name=American]
```

The DAO code is

```
public void addRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        String hql = "select max(id) from Recipe";
        Integer id = ((Integer) getSession().createQuery(hql).uniqueResult()) + 1;

        recipe.setId(id);
        getSession().save(recipe);
    }
```

From logs I can see following is getting inserted:

```
Hibernate: insert into cuisine (name, cuisine_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into recipe (cuisine_id, name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

My requirement is no new row is inserted in cuisine table as recipe.cusinie_id should store id only.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Without inserting new row in cuisine where you get cuisine_id? Do you insert cuisine first?

Answer (score 0):

The Recipe object passed to your DAO probably contains a reference to the Cuisine object. I assume both objects are not associated with the session at that time.

Your Annotations for the reference to Cuisine contains a `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`, telling Hibernate to also save the references Cuisine object. This results in your `insert into cuisine` statement.

You should probably remove the cascade annotation, since it would also cause the cuisine to be deleted when you delete a Recipe.

Another solution would be to load the Cuisine object from DB, and reference it in the Recipe before saving. (But that woul still leave you with the delete cascade)

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by "both objects are not associated with the session at that time". As Recipe class has declaration "private Cuisine cuisine", so both objects will get selected when query is made on "Recipe" class.

Comment: You call addRecipe() when you want to store a new Recipe, i.e. one that you was not just read from the database. Before the session.save(recipe) the recipe was just a data object, the session knew nothing about it. That is what I mean by "not associated with the session". The recipe also references a Cuisine object. I assume that this Cuisine object also was not read from the database, and that the session also knows nothing about that object. The Cascade annotation will cause hibernate to also save that object.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Removing cascade in the OneToOne annotation, made the code executable. But I landed up in another exception related to validation.. still scratching my head how that can be resolved..

Answer (score 0):

To your DAO method you are just passing a new instance of `Recipe` object and this object has parameters as mentioned in your question:

```
Recipe [id=0, name=Burger, cuisine=Cuisine [id=0, name=American]
```

Now in DAO method you are getting the max id from database and updating your `Recipe` instance with the new id value, so the properties of your recipe instance will become like this (assuming the max(id) in database is 100):

```
Recipe [id=101, name=Burger, cuisine=Cuisine [id=0, name=American]
```

You have `CASCADE TYPE` set to `ALL` between your `Recipe` entity and `Cuisine` entity, so when you try to save the `recipe` instance using the below line:

```
 getSession().save(recipe);
```

what hibernate will do is it will try to hit the database to get an instance of `cuisine` with `id` as `0` since your `recipe` has an instance of `cuisine` whose `id` is `0`.

```
select cuisine_.cuisine_id, cuisine_.name as name2_0_ 
    from cuisine cuisine_ 
    where
        cuisine_.cuisine_id=0
```

If there is no record in database for `cuisine` table with `id` as `0` then hibernate assumes that you are trying to save a new record for `cuisine` in database, so it will generate an `insert` query for `cuisine` also.

To avoid this `insert` query on `cuisine` table, make sure you are assigning the correct `id` to `cuisine` instance that is assigned to `recipe` object before calling your DAO method.

Comment: Sorry, I tried but code doesn't get executed. It is giving validation error at the Cuisine.Name.

Comment: (Using multiple comments to make my comments clear) I kept @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL).
and as you advised Hibernate ran select query on cuisine. But in the log, after running insert statement, it gave "javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.recipe.tables.Cuisine] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:["

Comment: @Sandeep, it is not clear on what you have tried and what is the exception you are getting now. Please update your question with exact code that you have tried and complete stacktrace of exception you are getting now.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` our code tells that first the reference has to be saved then the actual table values.

I see here that you are saving the whole transaction at one go.

Might be this code in DAO implementation might help.

```
public void addRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
    String hql = "select max(id) from Recipe";

    getSession().beginTransaction(); 
    Integer id = ((Integer) getSession().createQuery(hql).uniqueResult()) + 1;

    recipe.setId(id);

    getSession().save(recipe.getCuisine);
    getSession().save(recipe);
    getSession().getTransaction().commmit();

}
```

Comment: You code explicitly does what his code does implicitly: storing a cuisine object. And that is exactly what he wants to avoid. It is also not a good idea to do explicit transaction handling in a DAO method, since the method may be part of a larger transaction.

Comment: My bad I thought since the reference table is not affecting the explicit code might help and with transaction I guessed the data is not saved because may be the session is expecting more operations thats why I added transaction().commit().